# ¿Cómo puedo mostrar la dirección de memoria de un char?

Tags: c++

Este primer código muestra la dirección de i:

```
int i = 6;
cout << &i << endl;
```

Pero, ¿por qué este no funciona para un char?

```
char c = 'k';
cout << &c << endl;
```

El primero da una direccion razonable (0x61ff0c) pero el segundo muestra algo raro (k♠).
¿Cómo obtengo la dirección de un char?
Gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow, te invito a visitar el [tour] para aprender sobre el funcionamiento del sitio y, de paso, ganar tu primera medalla. Un saludo.

Comment: Ambas locales.Primer caso: 0x61ff0c Segundo caso: k♠

Answer (score 3):

Cuando tu haces `&a`, siendo `a` **un `char`**, el puntero resultante tiene el tipo `char *`.

Y, entre otras, [`std::ostream::operator<<( )`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt)tiene una sobrecarga para [poder usarlo con cadenas de caracteres](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2). Que justamente admite argumentos del tipo `const char *`.

Pues ya lo tenemos: al intentar volcar un puntero a `char`, se activa la sobrecarga adecuada (`const char *`), que espera justamente eso, **un puntero a una cadena**. E intenta interpretar su argumento como una cadena de caracteres.

Sin embargo, tu le estás pasando un puntero **a un solo carácter**. Por lo que, al intentar interpretarlo como lo que no es, provoca la salida que observas.

La solución mas simple: fuerza tu puntero al tipo `void *`:

```
char c = 'k';
cout << static_cast< void * >( &c ) << endl;
```